# Did Will Gorski have to be drugged almost 24/7 to keep whispers from finding his location?

Tags: sense8

When Sensates visit each other, they can really only feel/hear/see what the person they are visiting is experiencing. The whole debacle with keeping Will unconscious was so whispers wouldn't be able to travel to him and accidentally see/hear anything that would point to where they were hiding. Instead of being drugged to unconsciousness, could blindfolding and adorning noise-cancelling headphones be an alternative solution?

Since he was with Riley, could he not have traveled with his consciousness to her body and spent his time awake like that? They could have still spent time together and done normal things, he would just need to leave his body alone during the time he was awake. Whispers wouldn't be able to piggyback off of Will to Riley's consciousness, so he would have been safe... right?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You make a good point, though I'm not sure if the sensates are able to stay consistently connected to each other. The connection seems to be something that comes and goes, and something they can't always control. And being trapped in a state of total sensory deprivation with the voice of a murderous psychopath in your head could be considered worth than being strung out on heroin for extended periods of time.